# Maven Build in Eclipse without using Command prompt

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

I created the maven-spring project using the m2e plugin of eclipse. The project is working fine. I want to do a `Maven build in Eclipse` the project **without using any commands in command prompt** i.e. using the eclipse IDE only. But I am not able to find the option for Maven build from Eclipse IDE.

Below are the options I am getting when I right click on my project:

[image]

Kindly advise.

Comment: Try to right-click on pom.xml file.

Comment: Not familiar with Eclipse while using Maven, but if Eclipse knows this  is a project built with Maven, then shouldn't your build options in Eclipse now actually use Maven's build process not Eclipse's?

Comment: After right-click on `pom.xml`, go to the "Run As" menu (not the "maven" menu).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I got a popup windoe asking me for the `Goals`...Can you please let me know what should be the possible values and their need? IF possible please redirect me to a blog explaining the same

Comment: @user182944 [Here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) you go.

Comment: @user182944: Please post a new question; don't ask new questions in comments.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Please post your comments as answer so that I can accept them and close this thread.

Comment: @Martin I have deleted the earlier post and will be posting a new question for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click on `pom.xml`, then go to the "Run As" menu (not the "maven" menu). The various plug-in goals (and lifecycle targets) are documented [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html).

Answer (score 2):

you can follow this link, right click maven project -> run as -> maven build..
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_eclispe_ide.htm